# How exactly would one write a program to analyze a document and store key data in a csv file

Tags: export-to-csv, document

I am looking for a way to create a program or website that can accept a text document as input (like MS Word Docx), then analyze it for keywords. Once it finds certain key words in a certain combination, it would store then in a csv file with a pre-determined format for headers and such. Im a complete noob at programming, and a moderate beginner at web design, im just kinda exploring this a little. A non-programming friend run an idea by me, and this is how I thought part of the idea could be executed. I can’t disclose anyth
ing about what it would be used for because it would reveal the idea and maybe cause someone to make the idea real before we do.

I haven’t tried anything yet, im just trying to get some input from other people who may have done similar things.

Comment: Sounds like you are describing full text indexing. Conceptually, this is what we have been doing for many years in different domains, conceptually the process is very simple, iterate through the  document, use hints and a known model to capture common words and phrases. Chat GPT and other LLM indexing services do this now with very minimal effort. Sounds like you have some catching up to do. :)

Comment: This is not the right forum for this, but the bottom line is that with the minimum information you have here, it sounds like there are a lot of publicly available services you can use right now, you do not need to re-invent anything new here. That's not saying you couldn't commericalize this, but the next steps might be to engage a developer consultant directly for advice, at some point you will have to explain in detail to _one_ of us what you want to achieve.